# How to exporting a databse structure (or many tables) for import

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In TSQL: When right click a table you have the option to Script table as > Create

which creates the table script including the constraints
If you want to port the database or  large portion of the table:

is it possible to have a script create the tables in 1 file and the  FK constraints in another file. The 2 files can then be used to recreate the tables and relationships in another DB

Comment: Do you need to have them as separate files? Using the "Generate Scripts" option from right-clicking on a database allows you to script schema objects along with FKs into one script (with other options as well).

Comment: Using 'Generate Script' at the database level  is not generating the table Create scripts - it creates the script to define another DB. I would prefer a spate file for the FK associations so that they can be applied after all the tables are created therefore avoiding the logic of which table to create first.

Comment: sal, you may have be having permissions issues if you are using the  Generate Script task and tables aren't scripting.  Make sure you are actually navigating to the Generate Script task and not just selecting the "Script database as" option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Generate Script](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078(v=sql.105).aspx) feature to output what you need.

1. Right click on the database and select Task -> "Generate Scripts..."
2. Choose "Select specific database objects" and check the "Tables" box to script out all tables (and any other necessary objects, like schemas or database roles)
3. On the next dialogue, click the "Advanced" button and ensure that "Script Foreign Keys" is set to True.
4. Finish the wizard and output your script to a new window, clipboard, or file.

This will automatically order the object creation in the proper order so that you can run the entire script once to generate all tables/constraints/views/etc. that you need (tables, then constraints, then foreign keys, then extended properties, and so on).

Comment: John,Thanks the Generate > TASK options should give me what I need. The 1 thing I have noticed I can create scripts for the tables without the constraints though not the other way around. This takes me half way there - so I guess I can cut and manually paste the constraints to a 2nd file for execution after all the tables are created

Comment: You can include constraints if you look at the other options in the Advanced dialogue.

Comment: John, my concern was the constraints would follow immediately after the Create Table,. I have run a test - they are created after all the tables are created. You have provided me with the solution.  Thanks